# Diagonal elements of Hermitian matrices with given eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Given real vectors $d = (d_1, \ldots, d_n)$ and $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$, where I will assume that their coefficients are arranged in non-increasing order, the [Schur-Horn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem) says that there exists a Hermitian matrix with the diagonal given by $d$ and spectrum given by $\lambda$ if and only if $d \prec \lambda$, with $\prec$ denoting majorization (i.e. $ \sum_{i=1}^n d_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$,
and $ \sum_{i=1}^k d_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i$ for all $1 \leq k < n$). Given a vector of eigenvalues, the Schur-Horn theorem then tells us all of the possible diagonal values that Hermitian matrices with such eigenvalues can take. However, it does not take into consideration the eigen*vectors* of the matrices, and the subspace which they lie in. My question is about an extension of the theorem which does.

Given a vector of eigenvalues $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_r, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and a subspace $S$ representing the span of the eigenvectors corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues, what diagonal values can Hermitian matrices with this set of eigenvalues and with this column space take?

Does this set admit an easy characterization?

Comment: Does the subspace $S$ correspond to the non-zero eigenvalues?

Comment: @Mahdi Yes, sorry I wasn't clear about this!

Comment: Let the columns of $U_1$ be an orthonormal basis for $S$. Then $A=U_1\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r)U_1^T$ is a typical matrix with the desired property. On the other hand, diagonal entries of $A$ are equal to $u_i^T\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r)u_i$ where $u_i$s are rows of $U_1$. This give a (not very easy) characterization.